# Sort Multiple Array to Numeric order (1,2,....,9,10,11) and Alphabetical order in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

How can I sort multidimensional array in numeric order first and then in alphabetical order in PHP. I have one array :

```
{
"id": "220",
    "pin_list": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "1. La Sagrada Familia",
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "2. Park Guell",
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "name": "10. Casa Batllo",
        },
        {
            "id": "4",
            "name": "11. Cathedral of Barcelona",
        },
        {
            "id": "5",
            "name": "3. Picasso Museum",
        },
        {
            "id": "6",
            "name": "Zebra",
        },
        {
            "id": "7",
            "name": "Apple",
        },
        {
            "id": "8",
            "name": "Monkey",
        }
    ]
}
```

I want this array to sort in Numeric first and rest are in alphabetical order. So basically want array output like this :

```
{
"id": "220",
    "pin_list": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "1. La Sagrada Familia",
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "2. Park Guell",
        },
        {
            "id": "5",
            "name": "3. Picasso Museum",
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "name": "10. Casa Batllo",
        },
        {
            "id": "4",
            "name": "11. Cathedral of Barcelona",
        },
        {
            "id": "7",
            "name": "Apple",
        },
        {
            "id": "8",
            "name": "Monkey",
        },
        {
            "id": "6",
            "name": "Zebra",
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried natsort and array_multisort but not able to get desired output. Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`usort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) on the `pin_list` element of the array (assuming you have decoded this JSON to an associative array), using `strnatcmp` to compare the `name` values:

```
usort($array['pin_list'], function ($a, $b) {
    return strnatcmp($a['name'], $b['name']);
});
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/WdO6i)

Comment: wow!! working perfect !! saved lot of time, thanks.